# Proper way to fire events based on mysql datetime using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Currently working on a CRM project for a backoffice where users create new clients and define certain events like followup's, SLA controls, etc.

The idea is to fire notifications on the webpage but only for new events, for example, I would have a event to fire at 14:00 and another one at 14:15, but they would only fire once for each one.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? And which time interval should I be looking at to avoid struggling the mysql database?

Comment: You need to use cron job which is run on certain time for certain event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sine you have mentioned ajax I'm assuming you are referring to something similar to small popups you get on the browser.

If it is so, you need to use javascript to do the calling. I have read that people are using web sockets for real-time updates but I'd leave an expert here to guide you on it since I'm not familiar with it.

Also to do the popping up nicely you will have to use something like pnotify.

**Steps you need to follow.**

1. Have your javascript query the server every 5 minutes or so. The reason for me mentioning every 5 minutes is because the counter gets reset on a page load. Therefore, if the page/script gets loaded in 10 minutes, the next call will take 15 mins from that load. Therefore, you will need to decide on the interval value.

   ```
    <script>
       function getnewrecords(){
          $.ajax({ //notice I have used jquery to do the ajax calling.
                   url: "http://yourapiurl.org/api/function",
                   type: 'GET',
                   success: function(res) { //res is the ajax result
                   console.log(res); //console output
                   //call javascript notified plugins function to display popup here
                   }
           });
       }

       setInterval ( getnewrecords, 900000); //time mentioned in miliseconds. 1 second = 1000 ms. Therefore 60,000 * 15 = 900,000

   </script>
   ```
2. In your CI controller call the model and get db result. The time issue comes up here as well. So you might have to do some thinking about the logic. Such as the storing the last time this function wall called in a session and getting records inserted after such time.
   Do the model calling and echo out your needed output. The javascript will simply show the output from here. So you might have to consider the output format such as if needs to be a json object or not etc. Alternate your javascript code accordingly.

Things to note is the interval the javascript function is called, and a method of storing/identifying the last time the function was called in your CI.

Also, if you need to fire up something like an email, you will need to have a cronjob calling your CI url.

```
0 20 * * * wget yourCIurl/controller/function
```

cron will treat this like calling a regular http url.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, that helped me getting a idea how to do it.